# Why is this findAll request not returning any data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, I'm trying to pull a temperature value from www.theweathernetwork.com and when I inspect the element I'm getting the following structure:

```
<div class="mainTemp-wrap">
    <p class="temperature">
    14
    <span>
    °C
    </span>
    </p>
    <p class="mcity-feels-like">Feels like 
    <span>13</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

But when I run the following code, I get nothing returned:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.theweathernetwork.com/us/weather/illinois/chicago"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "temperature"})

print g_data
```

Comment: It looks like for the `url` provided it should be `soup.findAll("p", {"class": "temp"})`

Comment: The content is added dynamically so there is no p tag with the class temperature in what you get back

Comment: @CoryShay I was going to post an answer with the same thing, but the classes he is looking for are dynamically generated. Selenium will more than likely be the solution

Comment: @Wondercricket Taking a look further into things, when posting out the full contents of soup, though it's difficult to read to begin with, that the temperature values are there either. I'll take a look into Selenium.

Comment: @Wondercricket Just noticed that. AnabolicHippo, it does appear there is a call to get JSON information from their servers with a lot of the values but the keys are obfuscated to a point and Selenium would probably be your best bet.